# Center form box css

Tags: html, css

I have the following code for a form box

```
<form method="GET">
<input type="text" name="q" class="input center search" />
<input type="submit" class="btn submit">
</form>
```

How would I center the form box & submit button? I've tried `margin:auto`, `margin 0 auto` and `text-align:center`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: place it inside a div and use that instead of the input, or use the class on the form and not the input, since input is child of form

Comment: plus, `text-align:center` does not work for objects, only elements.

Comment: I think my solution is the most effiecient way of solving your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For margin auto to work, you need to specify a specific width. My solution:

```css
    #form {
      width: 200px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
```

```html
    <form method="GET" id="form">
      <input type="text" name="q" class="input center search" />
      <input type="submit" class="btn submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```css
form{
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid;
  padding:10px;
  }
```

```html
<form method="GET">
<input type="text" name="q" class="input center search" />
<input type="submit" class="btn submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Any way to remove the fact that it centers text inside the actual box?

Comment: Got it, and yes it's not necessary to center inside the text.. to remove the centered text, just remove the input class

Answer (score 1):

Put it into a `div` and use the settings below:

(you can add a `<br>` tag between the input elements if you want them below each other, as I did it below. If not, just erase that tag)

```css
.x {
  text-align: center;
}
form {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
<form method="GET">
<input type="text" name="q" class="input center search" />
  <br>
<input type="submit" class="btn submit">
</form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the inputs in a `div`, then add `text-align:center` to the `div`.

```css
.myInputs {
  text-align: center;
}
form {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<form method="GET">
  <div class="myInputs">
    <input type="text" name="q" class="input center search" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

If you want to have the submit button on a new line just add a `<br/>` before the submit button.

Comment: it is not right as you used text-align to be center where it could other element. how about another div element inside your div with some specified width?

Comment: A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Just add Your form in a div tag with the following id:-

```css
#inner{
 display: table;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
 <div id="inner">
 <form method="GET">
 <input type="text" name="q" class="input center search" />
 <input type="submit" class="btn submit">
 </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the box horizontally and vertically you can use the CSS code

```
    .input center search {
         position: relative;
         left: 50%;
         top: 50%;
         transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

To just center the box horizontally use the code

```
    .input center search {
         position: relative;
         left: 50%;
         transform: translate(-50%);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work perfectly:

```
form{
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  width:450px;
margin: 0 auto;
  }

input{
  text-align:center;
display: block;
width:120px;
  }
```